# respond_with return 200 instead of 422

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with active model validations that I am using to determine the validity of search terms...  If I call my controller endpoint with an invalid search, rails' respond_with is returning a 200 instead of a 422.

If I binding.pry inside my controller action, I see:
search_result.valid?
=> false

search_result.errors.full_messages
=> "Last name must be at least 2 characters"

...  So why am I getting a 200?

```
model:

    class SearchResult
      include ActiveModel::Validations
      validate :ensure_terms_presence_and_length

      attr_reader :attrs

      def initialize(attrs = {})
        @attrs = attrs
      end

      def users
        valid? ? SearchClient.search(attrs) : []
      end

      private

      def ensure_terms_presence_and_length
        if attrs.values.join.blank?
          errors.add(:base, 'search fields cannot be blank')
        else
          attrs.each do |key, value|
            errors.add(key, 'must be at least 2 characters') if value.length < 2
          end
        end
      end
    end

 controller:

    module Api::V1
      class SearchUsersController < ApiController
        respond_to :json

        def index
          search_result = SearchResult.new(permitted_params)
          respond_with search_result, serializer: SearchResultSerializer
        end

        private

        def permitted_params
          params.permit(
            :username,
            :first_name,
            :last_name,
            :email
          )
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some experimentation I found that, only the create / update actions will actually return a 422 status when there are errors--- However, you still have to manually call .valid? in order for respond_With to return that invalid status code + the serialized errors object.

If you use the show or index actions, rails does not care about valid? and will always return a 200.

Answer (score 0):

When responding to JSON, Rails defaults to a 200. You can specify the result in your controller using an if/else statement:

```
 if product.save
     render json: product, status: 201, location: product
   else
     render json: product.errors, status: 422
 end
```

Comment: I dont think this is true..  My other api controllers dealing with active record models as resources return 422s when they have errors.  It seems that this is only a problem with active model resources.